# Where does Glassfish 2.1 stores cached JSP?

Tags: jsp, caching, configuration, glassfish

I'm looking for some information I haven't found anywhere else, as title says: I cannot find where glassfish is storing JSP pages upon runtime compilation, I already looked in the following directories:

- **WEB-INF/jsp** under my deployed EAR, doesn't exist
- **domain1/generated/jsp/j2ee-apps/etc** etc has no .java files
- I made a search in the **whole glassfish folder** and I didn't find any .java files related to JSPs...

Any other hint?

Do I have to setup Glassfish in some way? Setup some properties? (I set jspCachingEnabled=true in the web-container only)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an IDE which takes control over Glassfish? If so, which?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios but am unable to set it up to deploy to Glassfish directly, I tried many times using the Add/Remove feature but didn't seem to work, server stays on [Republish] forever, so I deploy by hand using its admin console.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked in the title that you're using v2 instead of v3. I've had bad experiences with its Eclipse Plugin as well. The one for v3 is however more than awesome.

Comment: Well, at least it is not just my problem :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GlassFish does not keep the generated java sources for a jsp after they have been compiled by default.  You can change that by adding the following snippet into your sun-web.xml file...

```
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
```

If your jsp (mypage.jsp) is in a war file (mywebapp.war), then the java file will be under

```
%GLASSFISH_HOME%\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\j2ee-modules\mywebapp_war\org\apache\jsp\mypage_jsp.java
```

If your jsp (mypage.jsp) is in a war file (mywebapp.war) that is part of an EAR (myentapp.ear) then the java file will be under

```
%GLASSFISH_HOME%\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\j2ee-apps\myentapp\mywebapp_war\org\apache\jsp\mypage_jsp.java
```

Comment: The fun fact is that I found this same solution a couple hours after asking this question, I'm voting it up because correct, thankyou :) (now I need to know how to create my sun-web.xml)